# Add quotes in URL when printing it from a file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file named url.txt. There are several URL inside it.I want to print URL's from it. Ex. www.google.com. When i print it ,it printed as www.google.com.but i want to print www.google.com with quotes like "www.google.com".Here is my code:

```
file = open("url.txt","r") 
for line in file:
    myUrl = line
    print(myUrl)
```

It print as www.google.com!

Comment: `print('"%s"' % myUrl)`…?!

Comment: You need to wrap `line` within double quotes when you print: `f'"{line}"'`.

Comment: i used myUrl = '"%s"' % line but it printed "www.google.com

Answer (score 1):

you could for example do:

```
file = open("url.txt","r") 
for line in file:
    myUrl = "\"" + line[:-1] + "\""
    print(myUrl)
```

`\` is used to escape `"`, since it is a reserved symbol.

`+` is used to concatenate strings here.

`line[:-1]` is used to remove the trailing newline from `line`.

This solution assumes as deceze♦ mentioned in a comment that a trailing newline is guaranteed.

Also deceze♦ mentioned using `'"'` is simpler, so I now used that instead.

With the following solution you could also read in multiple URLs in a given line which are seperated by a delimiter [assuming this delimiter is used correctly]:

```
file = open("url.txt","r") 
myUrl = []
for line in file:
    delimiter = " " # enter your delimiter here
    i = line.count(delimiter)  # assuming delimiter is used correctly
    if i > 0:
        for j in range(0,i+1):
            myUrl = line.split(delimiter)[j]
            if j == i:
                myUrl = '"' + myUrl[:-1] + '"'
                print(myUrl)
                continue
            myUrl = '"' + myUrl + '"'
            print(myUrl)
    else:
        myUrl = '"' + line[:-1] + '"'
        print(myUrl)
```

Assuming a url.txt like so:

```
www.google.com
www.amazon.com www.duckduckgo.com www.stackoverflow.com
```

This would print:

```
"www.google.com"
"www.amazon.com"
"www.duckduckgo.com"
"www.stackoverflow.com"
```

Comment: This would be simpler using `'"'`; and removing the trailing newline this way is only a good idea if it's guaranteed that there *is* a newline, otherwise you're chopping off the last character.

Answer (score -1):

we can directly give the quotes in print.

```
file = open("url.txt","r") 
for line in file:
    myUrl = line
    print('"',myUrl,'"')
```